# How can I generate the ABI of my smart contract locally with foundry/forge?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, abi, foundry-forge

I have a project with multiple smart contracts locally and I want to generate the ABI of my `sc.sol` smart contract. I do wish to perform this locally using `forge` or `foundry`.
I know it is possible to do it on Remix or to use solc but I do not have these and wishes to use foundry/forge only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forge build` generates the contract artifacts in the `out` folder (by default).

You can parse the JSON artifact and read the `abi` section.

For example using the `jq` bash command:

```
forge build --silent && jq '.abi' ./out/MyContract.sol/MyContract.json
```

---

*src/MyContract.sol*:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.21;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {}
}
```

*Output of the above command:*

```
[
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "foo",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
  }
]
```

Comment: Okay. But those files have lots of other data within them...but no deployed addresses

Comment: @Russo `forge build` only compiles the contract, i.e. translates the human-readable Solidity code into machine-readable bytecode (and generates the ABI as a side-step to that). But it doesn't deploy the contract... In order to deploy a contract to a new address, you can use the [forge create](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/deploying) command. What it does in the background, it sends a transaction from your deployer address (signed by the deployer private key), containing the bytecode. And then the EVM node that produces a new blocks stores the contract bytecode and assigns it a new address.

Comment: Thank you. I will trim those file down to only ABIs and add deployment addresses.. for frontend usage